# Trying to install Samba on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop running on Raspberry Pi

Tags: 20.04, samba, raspberrypi

Hi I recently installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Pi and then installed Ubuntu Desktop.

I am now trying to install Samba so I can make a share with my Windows system but I am getting the following error when trying sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin or using:

```
chewie@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package samba-common-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  samba-libs

E: Package 'samba' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'samba-common-bin' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help or tell me why it isn't working?

Thanks so much for reading!

---

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe

Comment: `sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin` should be enough. Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before?

Comment: yes I did and upgrade

Comment: please [edit] your question and copy/paste the output of `grep -v '#' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I am new and it won't let me post more than 8 links. here is the rest of the output... deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse



deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal universe multiverse

Comment: deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted


deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted


deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates universe


deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal multiverse

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse

Comment: deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse



deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe

deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal universe multiverse

Comment: Can anyone say if that is the correct source list?

Comment: seems not be a correct sources.list. Backup the file, delete it and regenerate a new one with the `software-properties-gtk` program